# How to make a decimal variable hold/show decimal places, even if decimal places are only zeros?

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

Is there a way to make a decimal variable hold decimal places always. Even if the decimal places only have 0s.

E.g.:

> 10.00,
>   100.000,
>   1000.00,
>   etc.

I know we can do it with a string variable like `string.Format("{0:0.00}", stringVariable)` but can we do it with a decimal variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `10` and `010` represent the exact same decimal.  You can't change how the underlying decimal represents those values because they're simply not different.  You are wishing to change how you represent that decimal as a string, you can only do that once you have converted it to a string.

Comment: '...you can only do that once you have converted it to a string' -- answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Storing trailing zeros in a .NET `System.Decimal` is indeed possible.

Much like the binary `float` and `double` types, a `decimal` is stored as a sign bit, a significand, and a "scale" (exponent).  Unlike `float` and `double`, `decimal` values are not normalized, so the number 12345×10<sup>-2</sup> is internally different from 123450×10<sup>-3</sup>.  You can create these from strings using `Parse` or `TryParse`.

```
IronPython 2.7.1 (2.7.0.40) on .NET 4.0.30319.1008
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from System import *
>>> x = Decimal.Parse("123.45")
>>> y = Decimal.Parse("123.450")
>>> x.ToString()
'123.45'
>>> y.ToString()
'123.450'
```

Note that although `x` and `y` are represented differently, they compare the same.

```
>>> x == y
True
```

An alternative (but less programmer-friendly) approach that doesn't require an intermediate `string` object is to use [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the number's constituent parts:

```
>>> x = Decimal(12345, 0, 0, False, 2)
>>> y = Decimal(123450, 0, 0, False, 3)
```

However, in most cases, you really only care about *displaying* a certain number of decimal places rather than *storing* them.  This can be trivially accomplished using `string.Format`.

```
>>> String.Format("{0:0.00}", x)
'123.45'
>>> String.Format("{0:0.000}", x)
'123.450'
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimals are just numbers. There is no way to force the number itself to be equal to 10.0110

Like the other posters have said, you worry about what the decimal format will be once you need to convert it to a string for the user to see, not before.

Comment: `System.Decimal` *can* store significant trailing zeros.

Comment: Perhaps I should have have stated it more clearly. It can store a significant zero, but I believe what the OP wanted was to round the number of digits up from a lower precision and hold them arbitrarily.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use ToString() overloads, eg:

```
yourDecimal.ToString("0.000");
```

Comment: OP said he knew you can do it in a string, he want to do it to a decimal directly.

Comment: Well, sorry if you think it's unappropriate, but it seems unlogical to me to ask to "mantain" decimal parts if not relating to an output... and my solution works to give an output

Comment: So, -1 for a correct answer (not anybody do know about numeric ToString overload, without before casting them to string) and 0 for an unlogical question? That seems even more unlogical... But I take it.

Comment: Correct or not, it does not answer this question at all. OP wants to know about decimal, you just repeat what he said he knew about strings.